# Incremental updates in Hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am have a source MySql table. I have to export the date to Hive for analytical purpose. Initially when the data size in MySQL was less full export of Mysql data to Hive was not an issue using Sqoop. 
Now as my data size has grown how can I take incremental update of MySql data to hive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqoop for incremental update, Sqoop documentation is good, here is the link
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Just one more thing. How to handle "updated" entries as Hive is append only. We are yet to migrate to the updated Hive which support transaction.

Comment: Create a hive view on table resulting only new records 
Some thing like

    select t1.* from test t1
   join (
     select id, max(modifed) maxModified from test
         group by id
   ) s
    on t1.id = s.id and t1.modifed = s.maxModified

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on incremental update using hive/spark.

`scala> spark.sql("select * from table1").show
+---+---+---------+
| id|sal|timestamp|
+---+---+---------+
|  1|100|    30-08|
|  2|200|    30-08|
|  3|300|    30-08|
|  4|400|    30-08|
+---+---+---------+`

`scala> spark.sql("select * from table2").show
+---+----+---------+
| id| sal|timestamp|
+---+----+---------+
|  2| 300|    31-08|
|  4|1000|    31-08|
|  5| 500|    31-08|
|  6| 600|    31-08|
+---+----+---------+`

`scala> spark.sql("select b.id,b.sal from table1 a full outer join table2 b on a.id = b.id where b.id is not null union select a.id,a.sal from table1 a full outer join table2 b on a.id = b.id where b.id is null").show
+---+----+
| id| sal|
+---+----+
|  4|1000|
|  6| 600|
|  2| 300|
|  5| 500|
|  1| 100|
|  3| 300|
+---+----+`

Hope this logic is gonna work for you.